# visibleWhen for command to appear in context menu

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying configure visibility of a command within the context menu using 'visibleWhen' expression within a menuContribution.  What I am trying to do is make the command visible in the context menu only if you:

1. Right-click certain file types(resources) in the resource view (or package view)
2. Right-click the appropriate editor that has the file type open.  It can detect that my editor is open or that the editor has a certain resource open.

I've accomplished the first using 'visibleWhen'>'selection(with)'>'iterate'>'org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource(adapt)' then checking the file extension for the resource. The code is listed below. However, I'm not sure how to get the same command to only appear when you right-click the correct editor that has a file open with the correct extensions - ext1, ext2.

Checking if my editor is active resolves the second issue but doesn't seem to help since if I click on files that are not my type, it will still show the command in the context menu.

Any recommendations?
The "Eclipse Plug-ins (3rd Edition)" shows some example for editor context menu but it uses actions and I want to stick with commands.

Thanks!!

---

```
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?before=additions">
     <separator
           name="com.test.ide.separator1"
           visible="true">
     </separator>
     <menu
           icon="icons/sample.gif"
           label="Test Menu">
        <command
              commandId="com.test.commands.testCommand1"
              icon="icons/sample.gif"
              label="testCommand1"
              style="push"
              tooltip="This is a test command">
           <visibleWhen
                 checkEnabled="false">
              <with
                    variable="selection">
                 <iterate
                       ifEmpty="false"
                       operator="or">
                    <adapt
                          type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                       <or>
                          <test
                                property="org.eclipse.core.resources.extension"
                                value="ext1">
                          </test>
                          <test
                                property="org.eclipse.core.resources.extension"
                                value="ext2">
                          </test>
                       </or>
                    </adapt>
                 </iterate>
              </with>
           </visibleWhen>
        </command>
     </menu>
  </menuContribution>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it done with a `with` variable that I came across. Using the same code example above:

- Add an `<or>` block within the `<iterate>` block
- Place the existing `<adapt>` block in the new `<or>` block
- Add a new `with` variable called `activeEditorInput`

Here is the new code example.

```
<iterate ifEmpty="false" operator="or">
  <or>
    <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
      <or>
        ...test extensions
      </or>
    </adapt>
    <with variable="activeEditorInput">
      <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
        <or>
          ...test extensions
        </or>
      </adapt>
    </with>
  </or>
</iterate>
```

Comment: That's right, but I would suggest a slight restructuring optimization:

Answer (score 9):

@blissfool, I would suggest a slight restructuring.  You can put your basic test (which is correct) in a `org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions` block:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
   <definition id="org.eclipse.example.testExtension">
      <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
         <or>
             <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.extension"
                   value="ext1">
             </test>
             <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.extension"
                   value="ext2">
             </test>
         </or>
      </adapt>
   </definition>
</extension>
```

Then in your visibleWhen move the `activeEditorInput` test up to the top:

```
<visibleWhen>
   <or>
      <with variable="selection">
         <iterate ifEmtpy="false">
           <reference definitionId="org.eclipse.example.testExtension"/>
         </iterate>
      </with>
      <with variable="activeEditorInput">
        <reference definitionId="org.eclipse.example.testExtension"/>
      </with>
   </or>
</visibleWhen>
```

Comment: Ah. Right. Thanks for that. I read about org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions and thought about how I could reduce the repeated conditions but didn't put the two together.  I was too focused on getting the functionality to work. Cheers~ :)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own [PropertyTester](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/expressions/PropertyTester.html).

Comment: Thanks. I'm not too familiar with custom PropertyTester yet, or even much of the plug-in API yet. I did come across another "with" variable that helped me get this done!