# 'Visiblewhen' in eclipse menu. Want menu to only appear for particular file extensions

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

EDIT restating question and where I've got to:

I've now reduced the issue down to a very small example: I have an eclipse plugin with a menu. It looks like this:

[image]

I'd like that menu to only appear when viewing files of a particular file extension (let's say .txt for this example).

Using Greg's answer below I have the following plugin.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
         <menu
               id="ARTful.menus.sampleMenu"
               label="Hide Me"
               mnemonic="M">
            <command
                  commandId="ArtEditor.command.format"
                  id="ARTful.menus.sampleCommand"
                  mnemonic="S"
                  tooltip="Hello!">
            </command>

             <visibleWhen
       checkEnabled="false">
   <with variable="selection">
      <iterate
           ifEmpty="false">
         <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
              <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.extension" value="txt" />
         </adapt>
      </iterate>
   </with>
</visibleWhen>
</menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

With this setup:

[image]

But unfortunately this hides the menu for any and all file extensions.  What am I doing wrong?

ORIGINAL QUESTION FOLLOWS

I've tried the solutions found at [visibleWhen for command to appear in context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592028/visiblewhen-for-command-to-appear-in-context-menu) and in several other places.

I have an eclipse plugin with a menu. It looks like this:

[image]

I'd like that menu to only appear when viewing files of a particular file extension (It's called 'source', and so if looking at a say java file with the plugin install there are suddenly two 'source' menus and that's just plain unhelpful).

I'm using the 'visibleWhen' construct.

I've tried testing the extension property:

[image]

(resulting in this plugin.xml fragment)

```
<menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
         <menu
               id="ARTful.menus.sampleMenu"
               label="Source"
               mnemonic="M">
            <command
                  commandId="ArtEditor.command.format"
                  id="ARTful.menus.sampleCommand"
                  mnemonic="S"
                  tooltip="Format">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="ArtEditor.command.latex"
                  style="push"
                  tooltip="LaTex Output">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="ArtEditor.command.format.alpha"
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <visibleWhen
                  checkEnabled="false">
               <test
                     property="org.eclipse.core.resources.extension"
                     value="art">
               </test>
            </visibleWhen>


             </menu>

      </menuContribution>
```

But the menu is entirely hidden, even when I want to be visible. I've also tried testing the name property...

[image]

Which gives:

```
  <visibleWhen
          checkEnabled="false">
       <test
             property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
             value="*.art">
       </test>
    </visibleWhen>
```

But still hidden.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use something like:

```
<visibleWhen
       checkEnabled="false">
   <with variable="activeMenuSelection">
      <iterate
           ifEmpty="false">
         <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
              <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.extension" value="art" />
         </adapt>
      </iterate>
   </with>
</visibleWhen>
```

The `with` establishes that you are working with the active context menu selection, this is not strictly necessary as it is the default. For a main menu the with value should be `selection`.

The current selection is a list so you need to use `iterate` to step through it.

The objects shown in views such as the Package or Project explorer are not actually the files but some user interface object representing the files. You need to use `adapt` to invoke the adapter manager on the user interface object to get the object you want. I have used `IResource` here because adapters to `IFile` are less common.

If you define a `content type` for your file type you can use something like:

```
<test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.contentTypeId" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.javaSource" />
```

for the test. This is a bit more flexible than relying on the file extension. The value shown in my example is for Java source files.

To show a menu when a particular editor is active using something like:

```
<with
    variable="activeEditorId">
    <equals
         value="org.eclipse.ant.ui.internal.editor.AntEditor">
   </equals>
</with>
```

which tests for the Ant editor.

Comment: So I learned a lot from your explanation (and have thus upvoted) but unfortunately this still hides the menu in *all* circumstances... I'll have a little bit more of a play (all though advice on debugging this would be helpful... I'm pretty sure I CAN'T put a breakpoint in the xml...

Comment: I tested this before I posted it here and it works for me. What view (Package Explorer, Project Explorer, ...) are you working with?

Comment: Ah - there may be some confusion (my fault, I should have been clearer and the question I linked to didn't help) I'm looking at a main menubar menu rather than a context menu - does that make a difference? (I've edited the question to be clearer)?

Comment: For a main menu the `with` variable should be `selection`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still struggling - I've reduced my example down as far as I could where I still see the behavior and I've posted the updated plugin.xml to the question in the hope that makes things easier... :(

Comment: When an editor is active the current selection is usually some of the text being edited. You can test the active editor id instead - added to answer.

Comment: Sigh... Nothing is ever simple in Eclipse :-( You spend X time implementing what an action/command does, then you spend at least 4*X trying to make it appear in the UI in the right place by writhing this horrible, undebuggable XML without any real feedback on why your XML doesn't seem to work. Thanks for the answer though. At least with that I have some good info on how to figure it out.